# c++ regex extract all substrings using regex_search()

Tags: c++, regex

I am new to c++ regex. I have a string "{1,2,3}" and I want to extract the numbers 1  2  3. I thought I should use regex_search but it failed.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<regex>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
        string s1("{1,2,3}");
        string s2("{}");
        smatch sm;
        regex e(R"(\d+)");
        cout << s1 << endl;
        if (regex_search(s1,sm,e)){
                cout << "size: " << sm.size() << endl;
                for (int i = 0 ; i < sm.size(); ++i){
                        cout << "the " << i+1 << "th match" <<": "<< sm[i] <<  endl;
                }
        }
}
```

The result:

```
{1,2,3}
size: 1
the 1th match: 1
```

Comment: You probably want to use [`regex_match()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match) with an appropriate expression describing this format.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[std::regex_search](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search) returns after only the *first* match found.

What [std::smatch](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results) gives you is all the matched groups in the regular expression. Your regular expression only contains one group so [std::smatch](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results) only has one item in it.

If you want to find all matches you need to use [std::sregex_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator).

```
int main()
{
    std::string s1("{1,2,3}");
    std::regex e(R"(\d+)");

    std::cout << s1 << std::endl;

    std::sregex_iterator iter(s1.begin(), s1.end(), e);
    std::sregex_iterator end;

    while(iter != end)
    {
        std::cout << "size: " << iter->size() << std::endl;

        for(unsigned i = 0; i < iter->size(); ++i)
        {
            std::cout << "the " << i + 1 << "th match" << ": " << (*iter)[i] << std::endl;
        }
        ++iter;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{1,2,3}
size: 1
the 1th match: 1
size: 1
the 1th match: 2
size: 1
the 1th match: 3
```

The `end` iterator is default constructed by design so that it is equal to `iter` when `iter` has run out of matches. Notice at the bottom of the loop I do `++iter`. That moves `iter` on to the next match. When there are no more matches, `iter` has the same value as the default constructed `end`.

**Another example to show the submatching (capture groups):**

```
int main()
{
    std::string s1("{1,2,3}{4,5,6}{7,8,9}");
    std::regex e(R"~((\d+),(\d+),(\d+))~");

    std::cout << s1 << std::endl;

    std::sregex_iterator iter(s1.begin(), s1.end(), e);
    std::sregex_iterator end;

    while(iter != end)
    {
        std::cout << "size: " << iter->size() << std::endl;

        std::cout << "expression match #" << 0 << ": " << (*iter)[0] << std::endl;
        for(unsigned i = 1; i < iter->size(); ++i)
        {
            std::cout << "capture submatch #" << i << ": " << (*iter)[i] << std::endl;
        }
        ++iter;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{1,2,3}{4,5,6}{7,8,9}
size: 4
expression match #0: 1,2,3
capture submatch #1: 1
capture submatch #2: 2
capture submatch #3: 3
size: 4
expression match #0: 4,5,6
capture submatch #1: 4
capture submatch #2: 5
capture submatch #3: 6
size: 4
expression match #0: 7,8,9
capture submatch #1: 7
capture submatch #2: 8
capture submatch #3: 9
```

Comment: Thank you. Can I ask what "end" is for? Looks like you didn't initialize it. std::sregex_iterator end;

Comment: @daydayup The `end` iterator is default constructed by design so that it is equal to `iter` when `iter` has run out of matches. Notice at the bottom of the loop I do `++iter`. That moves `iter` on to the next match. When there are no more matches, `iter` has the same value as the default constructed `end`. I added another example to show the submatching.