# C++ Regular expressions * saving only last matched

Tags: python, c++, regex, c++11

This is a very simple example to explain the problem I am facing regularly.

This is my code for processing a text file a.txt using regular expressions 
containing only the text "0123456789" , ie str after reading the file becomes this string.

Now I wanted each of the numbers to be in a separate index of the match array.

Like match[1] should give 0 match[2] should give 1 .. but instead what happens is only the last matched in * is retained ie match[1] gives us 9.

If we take the regular expression as "([0-9]*)" then the entire string will
be in match[1] which is not required.

How to retain all of them in separated manner ?

I faced a similar issue in python regex also where the same happens only the last matched is retained.

Again I emphasise that this is a very basic example of what I am facing but is on the exact lines of what I am facing which will be very difficult to explain here.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include<regex>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("a.txt");//open the input file

    stringstream strStream;
    strStream << inFile.rdbuf();//read the file
    string str = strStream.str();//str holds the content of the file

    regex r4("([0-9])*");

    if (std::regex_search(str, match, r4)) {
        cout<<match[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: You need https://ideone.com/7QNwCv, use a regex iterator to get multiple matches. You can only get the first match with `regex_search` and there are as many submatches as there are capturing groups in the pattern.

Comment: One set of parens `()` means only on capture group means only one index (excluding `0`). I don't think what you want is possible without adding all the capture groups. What is the greater problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: This answer may be of use https://stackoverflow.com/a/32553718/3807729