# Why is C++ regex so slow?

Tags: c++, regex

I am new to C++ and have to process a text File. I decided to do this with a Regex. The Regex I came up with:

```
(([^\\s^=]+)\\s*=\\s*)?\"?([^\"^\\s^;]+)\"?\\s*;[!?](\\w+)\\s*
```

I have written my C++ code according to the following Post:

[c++ regex extract all substrings using regex_search()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32553593/c-regex-extract-all-substrings-using-regex-search)

Here is the C++ Code:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <chrono>
#include <iterator>

void print(std::smatch match)
{
}

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file{ "D:\\File.txt" };
    std::string fileData{};

    file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    fileData.reserve(file.tellg());
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    fileData.assign(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file), 
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

    static const std::string pattern{ "(([^\\s^=]+)\\s*=\\s*)?\"? 
    ([^\"^\\s^;]+)\"?\\s*;[!?](\\w+)\\s*" };
    std::regex reg{ pattern };
    std::sregex_iterator iter(fileData.begin(), fileData.end(), reg);
    std::sregex_iterator end;

    const auto before = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::for_each(iter, end, print);

    const auto after = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> delta = after - before;
    std::cout << delta.count() << "ms\n";

    file.close();
}
```

The file I am processing contains 541 lines. The Program above needs 5 SECONDS to get all the 507 matches. I have done things like this before in C# and never had a Regex this slow. So I tried the same thing in C#:

```
var filedata = File.ReadAllText("D:\\File.txt", Encoding.Default);

const string regexPattern = 
    "(([^\\s^=]+)\\s*=\\s*)?\"?([^\"^\\s^;]+)\"?\\s*;[!?](\\w+)\\s*";

var regex = new Regex(regexPattern, RegexOptions.Multiline |      
    RegexOptions.Compiled );
    var matches = regex.Matches(filedata);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

This needs only 500 MILLISECONDS to find all 507 matches + printing it on the Console. Since I have to work with C++ I need to be faster.

How can I make my C++ Program faster? What do I do wrong?

Comment: How did you compile your programm? Did you use `-O2` or `-O3`? What is your compiler version?

Comment: You also should take a look at [raw string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) (#6), so you don't have to escape your regex (which is very error-prone imho)

Comment: @strangeqargo: In C++ he reads all his file date once.  He initializes the std::string `fileData` and then iterates over that.

Comment: should be something compiler-related then @MartinBonner

Comment: What compiler/standard library are you using? Not all regex implementations are created equal.

Comment: Please confirm that you did not benchnmark a debug executable. They can be magnitudes slower, esp MSVC and iterators.

Comment: @hellow I am using Visual Sudio 2017. I did not edit anything in the project properties so I assume I use the default. But I don't know what the default is. I try to find out more about it.

Comment: You are using the Debug build. On the top of the screen, there should be a drop-down called "Debug", when you click on that, you can change that to "Release"

Comment: Measure with a timer across the entire block of execution of the code you are testing from file open to file close. You don't show us where you measured your code execution in the C# example. For all we know, you are excluding the time it takes to load the file and parse it.

Comment: Nevermind @Thomas is totally right its way faster in release build (100ms). But why does it make such a big different?

Comment: Because in debug build optimizations are turned off.

Comment: @MasterR8, Even leaving compiler optimizations out, debug builds often have extra checks that help to catch bugs. For example, Microsoft's iterators will do constant checking that they are valid and dereferenceable, even if a pointer would suffice as an iterator otherwise. It's a lot slower, but it's a lot better at telling you when you're doing something wrong instead of possibly having the issue go unnoticed for an arbitrary period of time.

Comment: Not that it will make much difference, but you should pass your match by `std::match const& match` to the `print` function to prevent a superfluous copy.

Comment: Can you try `std::regex::optimize`? i am curious, if there is a difference...

Comment: @OZ17 It makes no difference at all

Comment: FYI: There are a lot of questions on SO and not only about why C++ regex is slow, and it seems the general consensus is that Boost regex is a better alternative, since it contains fewer glitches.

Comment: <250ms in Java including the I/O. Can you provide sample input?

Answer (score 3):

I just encountered the same problem, finally I replaced `std::regex` with `boost::regex`, I think you may also try another regex library(boost/google re2...).

Update:
I am using GCC 5.4.

Answer (score 3):

I mentioned C-style string but I didn't mean that using pure C-style as much as we can could improve the performance of regex. What I meant is simply that we should be able to do more things at compile time and to do less operations on `std::string` at runtime so that we can get a better performance.

**Original Answer**

As you know, we have two types of string: C-style string and `std::string`.

`std::string` is OK to be used while we coding but we can say that it's a kind of heavy stuff (this is why some people dislike it). First, `std::string` used the heap memory meaning that it used `new` or `malloc`; Second, `std::string` used some kind of specific algorithm while its size increasing (double the current size and move the current content into the new memory zone and free the old). These would cause the performance issues.

The Regular Expression is obviously all about string, it needs to play with string everywhere. `std::regex` plays a lot with `std::string`, that's why the performance of `std::regex` is not good.

Furthermore, `std::string` is totally a runtime stuff. For example, you can initialize a C-style string at compile time but you can't initialize a `std::string` at compile time. This means that things about `std::string` can rarely be optimized at compile time.
Here is an example about how we can utilize the compile time to get a very good performance at runtime: [Why is initialization of variable with constexpr evaluated at runtime instead of at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65990306/why-is-initialization-of-variable-with-constexpr-evaluated-at-runtime-instead-of)

`std::regex` can't do much thing at compile time because it uses `std::string`, this could cause the performance issue too. And this is why people may like CTRE (compile time regular expression) libraries.

If `std::string_view` can be used in the source code of `std::regex`, I think the performance would be better.

C++ promise: “don’t pay for what you don’t use.” No offense to anyone, but I personally kind of think that `std::regex` broke the promise. If  C++ standards committee believes that function is more important than any other things, I would say why don't use Java.

Comment: No idea why down vote. `boost::regex` used much less `new` and less `std::string`, that's why it has a much better performance. Take a c++ profiler to verify what I said.

Comment: C-style strings are missing something rather important: their length. Certainly allocations are expensive, and algorithms that create and destroy std::string objects without a thought could easily end up doing a lot of allocation, but creating and destroying C-style strings will *certainly* involve a lot of allocation, and `malloc` is not cheaper than `new`. There's no point in using footguns like C-style strings for this. Instead, postpone creating strings until the appropriate moment.

Comment: ... or maybe just hoist the actual reason for using C string literals to the top of your answer: it does make sense that the compiler would have an easier time evaluating constexpr code involving them at compile time, and `strlen` is obviously quite speedy then, too.

Comment: @SamB I know what you meant. I just added a postscript into this answer. I'm not an expert on C++ and didn't read the source code of C++ std library. So I can't make it more clear. What we've already known is that there must be some ways to improve the performance of `std::regex` because at least `boost::regex` has been there for a long time which has a very good performance.